# Reassociate file types with Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2003, file-association

I have a dual setup development machine with Visual Studio 2003 and 2005.

How can I restore the original file associations to Visual Studio 2003?

Everytime I try to open up a *.cs file it opens it with 2005 when I want it to default open up in 2003.

I know how to do this using the the "Windows Explorer/Folder Options/File Types" interface, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to restore the associated file types back to Visual Studio 2003.

Edit:

In Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 you can restore file associations by following the menu links: 
Tools > Options > Environment > General > Restore File Associations

In order to restore file associations for Visual Studio 2003 you have to rerun the installation dvd and specify repair install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible to run VS.NET 2003 Repair in order to restore file associations for VS.NET 2003

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you try the following (sorry, I only have VS 2008, but I hope VS 2005 has this too):

Tools > Options > Environment > General > Restore File Associations

Comment: I can confirm that VS2005 also has that button.

Comment: I can confirm that VS2003 doens't have this button!

Comment: @Makach: from your quesion it sounds like you don't want it in VS2003; just restore file associations in VS2005 and the files should default to that one.